# Convert void pointer and length to contiguous 1D typed memoryview in Cython

Tags: python, cython, ffi

I have an existing function I'd like to adapt. Currently, it takes an array of floats, e.g.

`[[1.0, 1.5], [2.2, 3.2], …]`

Passes it to my ffi function as a void pointer and length, and casts the transformed result back. This works perfectly. However, I need to adapt this for a second function which *accepts* the same array shape, but *returns* results as a void pointer to a contiguous 1D array of int (e.g. `[1, 4, …]`) and length. The returned data may be shorter than the input data.

This is my current function:

```
struct Array:
    void* data
    size_t len


def foo(coords):
    cdef double[:,::1] ncoords = np.array(coords, dtype=np.float64)
    cdef Array coords_ffi
    coords_ffi.data = <void*>&ncoords[0, 0]
    coords_ffi.len = ncoords.shape[0]
    # mutate
    cdef Array result = foo_ffi(coords_ffi)
    # convert back from pointer to coords e.g. [[1.0, 2.0], [2.1, 2.2], … ]
    cdef double* incoming_ptr = <double*>(result.data)
    cdef double[:, ::1] view = <double[:result.len,:2:1]>incoming_ptr

    if isinstance(coords, numpy.ndarray):
        outgoing = np.copy(view)
    else:
        outgoing = np.copy(view).tolist()
    drop_float_array(result)
    return outgoing
```

So I need to alter the lines:

```
    cdef double* incoming_ptr = <double*>(result.data)
    cdef double[:, ::1] view = <double[:result.len,:2:1]>incoming_ptr
```

to something like

```
cdef int* incoming_ptr = <int*>(result.data)
cdef int[???] view = <int[:result.len, ??]>incoming_ptr
```

But I can't figure out the array cast syntax for the second line.

Comment: Is this close to what you want? `cdef int[::1] view = <int[:ncoords.shape[0] * ncoords.shape[1]]>incoming_ptr`

Comment: @oz1 No…the returned data length could be shorter than the outgoing data (`ncoords`), so I can't use its `shape` properties, only the `result.data` property in the `<...>incoming_ptr` part.

Comment: I believe the real buffer length of the pointer should be returned from `foo_ffi`, otherwise, how can one use the pointer safely.

Comment: @oz1 `foo_ffi` does return the real buffer length – it returns an `Array` (see declaration), and its `len` field is the real buffer length.

Comment: We have the pointer and it's length, so`cdef int[::1] view = <int[:result.len]>incoming_ptr` is sufficient. But I can't believe it's this that bothering you, since you already gave an example of casting a pointer to 2d memory view

Comment: @oz1 You're absolutely correct: I shouldn't be using `int`, since the array contents are actually `size_t`, so `cdef size_t* incoming_ptr = <size_t*>(result.data)` followed by `cdef size_t[::1] view = <size_t[:result.len]>incoming_ptr` works. Sorry!